# No wifi on macbookpro7,1 running lubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, broadcom, macbook

I am aware of the many posts regarding how to get broadcom wifi cards working with the bcmwl-kernel-source or firmware-b43-installer drivers. I've read through everything and have tried everything but have gotten no results. Please help!

I have BCM4322 [14e4:432b]. I tried (from a clean install of lubuntu 16.04) remove --purge of bcmwl-kernel-source, installing that same driver and then rebooting and making sure that the driver was selected in the "Additional Drivers" tab of "Software & Updates". After this didn't work, I tried removing bcmwl-kernel-source and then installing firmware-b43-installer. rfkill list shows that nothing is blocked. Also, secure boot options is deactivated.

Any ideas? Please let me know if you need any other info.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 18 Jun 2017 20:28 EDT -0400

Booted last: 18 Jun 2017 00:00 EDT -0400

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 09:39:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Lubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:008d]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1684] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1684]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05ac:8403 Apple, Inc. Internal Memory Card Reader
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 05ac:8213 Apple, Inc. Bluetooth Host Controller
Bus 004 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 05ac:8242 Apple, Inc. Built-in IR Receiver
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05ac:0236 Apple, Inc. Internal Keyboard/Trackpad (ANSI)
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ac:8507 Apple, Inc. Built-in iSight
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

'pccardctl' is not installed (package "pcmciautils").

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

b43                   413696  0
bcma                   61440  1 b43
mac80211              761856  1 b43
cfg80211              581632  2 b43,mac80211
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    16384  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
ssb                    65536  1 b43

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.113  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::33aa:c1a2:57b9:95e7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2996 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3583276 (3.5 MB)  TX bytes:242052 (242.0 KB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:53603 (53.6 KB)  TX bytes:53603 (53.6 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp3s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp3s0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       617     1  1 20:27 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         tg3
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.137
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               5764m-v3.38
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp3s0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       f1759c8f-d4c3-33ea-b0f4-02717027f5f5
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   f1759c8f-d4c3-33ea-b0f4-02717027f5f5 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.113/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.1.113
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_rebinding_time = 75600
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       wpad = a
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       dhcp_renewal_time = 43200
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       expiry = 1497918502
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       host_name = gsevensonmac
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[29]:                       next_server = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[30]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[31]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::33aa:c1a2:57b9:95e7/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (AirPort Extreme)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         b43
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.8.0-36-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/0000:02:00.0/ssb0:0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp3s0    no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 54 : 5.27 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 58 : 5.29 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 62 : 5.31 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 102 : 5.51 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 106 : 5.53 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results

##### module infos ######################

[b43]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/b43/b43.ko
firmware:       b43/ucode9.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode5.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode16_mimo.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode15.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode14.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode13.fw
firmware:       b43/ucode11.fw
license:        GPL
author:         Rafał Miłecki
author:         Gábor Stefanik
author:         Michael Buesch
author:         Stefano Brivio
author:         Martin Langer
description:    Broadcom B43 wireless driver
srcversion:     50DEB95D1C49A54E9455F70
depends:        mac80211,ssb,bcma,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bad_frames_preempt:enable(1) / disable(0) Bad Frames Preemption (int)
parm:           fwpostfix:Postfix for the .fw files to load. (string)
parm:           hwpctl:Enable hardware-side power control (default off) (int)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (int)
parm:           hwtkip:Enable hardware tkip. (int)
parm:           qos:Enable QOS support (default on) (int)
parm:           btcoex:Enable Bluetooth coexistence (default on) (int)
parm:           verbose:Log message verbosity: 0=error, 1=warn, 2=info(default), 3=debug (int)
parm:           pio:Use PIO accesses by default: 0=DMA, 1=PIO (int)
parm:           allhwsupport:Enable support for all hardware (even it if overlaps with the brcmsmac driver) (int)

[bcma]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/bcma/bcma.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Broadcom's specific AMBA driver
srcversion:     B7DE883B3F397175C3EA03D
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     C63473656FCDBBDA56E12DA
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     F170FED576AF12B070D2E69
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

[ssb]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/ssb/ssb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Sonics Silicon Backplane driver
srcversion:     B01F6C607321CF055F3D5A7
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.8.0-36-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

##### module parameters #################

[b43]
allhwsupport: 0
bad_frames_preempt: 0
btcoex: 1
hwpctl: 0
hwtkip: 0
nohwcrypt: 0
pio: 0
qos: 1
verbose: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/libpisock9.conf]
blacklist visor

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   15.717303] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4322 WLAN found (core revision 16)
[   15.760602] b43-phy0: Found PHY: Analog 8, Type 4 (N), Revision 4
[   15.760625] b43-phy0: Found Radio: Manuf 0x17F, ID 0x2056, Revision 3, Version 0
[   31.388488] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp3s0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   32.237085] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   32.440211] b43-phy0: Loading firmware version 666.2 (2011-02-23 01:15:07)
[   32.908249] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[   35.148864] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[   35.148874] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX
[   35.148893] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp3s0: link becomes ready
[   57.760005] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is down
[   69.018114] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is up at 1000 Mbps, full duplex
[   69.018125] tg3 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Flow control is on for TX and on for RX

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: I've moved all comments to a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60788/discussion-on-question-by-gcolumbus-no-wifi-on-macbookpro7-1-running-lubuntu-16), both of you have access to talk in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried the generally accepted driver suite for the device, bcmwl-kernel-source. We have confirmed that you installed the latest version possible. This driver produced the errors that are found often and usually for your exact 14e4:432b device:

```
ERROR @wl_cfg80211_scan : WLC_SCAN error (-22)
<snip> and many others
```

You have tried the b43 and ssb driver suite and installed the needed firmware. While a wireless interface is created and Network Manager tries to manage it, it also results in errors:

```
state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
```

We know from the aliases that neither the driver brcmsmac nor brcmfmac drive your device.

I believe your options are now narrowed down to two:

- Buy a fully supported USB wireless. This post may be helpful to you in selecting one: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359573&p=13639455#post13639455
- Try the live USB or DVD of both 17.04 and 14.04 to see if a later or even an earlier version of Ubuntu is working.

I regret that I can see no way currently to get your device working.