# Can't connect to wifi on Ubuntu 16.04, have tried many things

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, broadcom

I've run through this tutorial, [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) and still can't see any of my wireless network options. I'm on the Broadcom Wireless Card [14e4:432b] (rev 01). When I check additional drivers, I've got the "Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcwml-kernel-source" selected. I've tried updating my packages and PCI.IDs, removing and reinstalling my bcwml-kernel-source driver and rebooting, What else do I have to try?

This is very frustrating, I just wanna use the Internet...
I'm on a Macbook Pro7.1 Version 1.0. Results of lshw

```
    sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 8c:7b:9d:d6:46:3d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:21 memory:d3200000-d3203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5764M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: 10:9a:dd:5b:e7:cd
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=5764m-v3.38 ip=192.168.0.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:27 memory:d3100000-d310ffff
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/926821/no-wifi-on-macbookpro7-1-running-lubuntu-16-04-lts/927177#927177

Comment: Kindly post the output results of cmd " lshw -C network" and Which make is your laptop ?

Comment: @SAGARBHOOSHAN edited post.  Does this help?